# pass a object parameter as const and read it

Tags: c++, constants, armadillo

This is probably a silly question, but I cannot solve this problem.

I have an object called equations, where inside is defined a matrix called X.

In the main, I need to call a function called f where I need to pass the matrix as a const.
I need to access to a specific position of the matrix (I don’t want to write, just want to read).

I do the following:

```
vec f(cx_mat const*X)
{
cout << “X[12][12] = “ << *X(12,12) << endl;
}
```

And it doesn’t work. If I do:

```
vec f(cx_mat const*X)
{
mat X_temp;
X_temp = *X;
cout << “X[12][12] = “ << X_temp(12,12) << endl;

}
```

I works, and I cannot understand why!!!
Can you help me?

Comment: It's just an idea: it may depend on the operator precedence. Try `cout << “X[12][12] = “ << (*X)(12,12) << endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (*X)(12,12) instead.

Function call operator "()" has higher precedence than indirection operator "*".

Answer (score 0):

In your second example you are creating a copy of mat object, which doesn't call any non-const methods of X. This is actually a solution to your problem, although not really effective - I'd prefer to avoid unnecessary copies.

So, most likely, mat class have operator=(const mat&) function defined.

Apart from approach which you found there are also other possibilities:

1. If you're able to change class mat, you can make operator() signature const. This will solve the problem.
2. If you cannot change mat interface, it is better to change f's signature to a non-const parameter reference, since without being able to change mat interface, you cannot really guarantee that operator() doesn't change X's state.
3. Use const_cast. I strongly suggest not to use that. I mention it here only for completeness.